# cannot design uicollectionview as I want

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

cannot have 3 cells for row with this collectionView.

- added UICollectionView via storyboard, same for cell, then aded constraints. All the other stuff is made via code.
- if I let cell empty, I have them perfectly square, but they are 6 for row on iPhone 11
- if add some outlets, as IE an image and a label in a stack (pinned 0,0,00 fil,fill), they are not equally distributed
- something changes if I give constraints via code in the cell to the image, but the result is never what I expect, 3 cells per row.
- both methods are failing

my controller

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    var collectionData = ["1", "2", "3 ", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        myCollectionView.delegate = self
        myCollectionView.dataSource = self
        configureCollectionView()
    }
    
    
    private func configureCollectionView() {
        
        let widthOfScreen = (view.frame.size.width - 20) / 3
        let layout = myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: widthOfScreen , height: widthOfScreen )
        layout.sectionInset =  UIEdgeInsets(top: 40.0,
                                            left: 10.0,
                                            bottom: 40.0,
                                            right: 10.0)
    }
    
    
    
    private func configureCollectionView2() {
        let width = view.bounds.width
        let padding: CGFloat = 12
        let minimumItemSpacing: CGFloat = 10
        let availableWidth = width - (padding * 2) - (minimumItemSpacing * 2)
        let itemWidth = availableWidth / 3
        
        let layout = myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
        layout.sectionInset =  UIEdgeInsets(top: padding,
                                            left: padding,
                                            bottom: padding,
                                            right: padding)
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemWidth)
    }
    
    
    
    
}


extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print(self.collectionData[indexPath.item])
    }
    
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {

    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return collectionData.count
    }
    
    
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let model = collectionData[indexPath.item]
        let cell = myCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: MyCollectionViewCell.reuseId, for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
        cell.configure(with: model)
        
        return cell
    }
    
    
}
```

my cell

```
import UIKit

class MyCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    static let reuseId = "MyCollectionViewCell"
    
//    @IBOutlet weak var myCellImage: UIImageView!
//    @IBOutlet weak var myCellLabel: UILabel!
    
    
    func configure(with: String) {
        
        backgroundColor = .systemPink
//        myCellImage.backgroundColor = .black
        
//        myCellImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
//
//        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
//
//            myCellImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
//            myCellImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
//
//        ])

        
    }
    
    
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- For when the cell is empty: You need to add some spacing between the cells so you can have 3 cells in a row; the easiest way to do it, is from the collection view size inspector under min spacing, the cell one is for horizontal spacing, and the line for vertical spacing.
- And for when adding outlets: One way to go about it is to set the height and width of at least one of these outlets.

P.S. You need to add spacing in both scenarios.

Comment: but doing it in code, I added minimumItemSpacing, are you talking about something different?

Comment: Yes I just saw that, but I believe you assigned that value to the size of the cells rather than the spacing between cells.